Differentiate two Cyrillic strings
When I run a query for this string in SQLite with these entries in Cyrillic in a text field, I only find one.

When I put the two strings in two different cells in Excel and search, it only finds the one I copied and pasted in the search prompt.
aфpиканeц
африканец
I tried checking the encoding on these strings too, but both of them are UTF-8 according to the tools I tried in.
What am I missing?  Why does Excel and the SQLite DB don't see them as the same string?

Excel and SQL see them as different strings because they are different strings. The first string aфpиканeц uses latin characters for the 'a' (0x61) and 'p' (0x70): (note the lack of encoding for them)

While the second string uses all cyrillic characters, including 'а' (0x430) and 'р' (0x440) respectively. африканец =


Could you share the tool you are using to determine this?  I also want to be able to be able to convert all of my data so I don't get these "dupes" (or not so dupes as you show here.

@Karlomanio https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ , I just googled for "Text to Unicode" haha

Thanks,  I was searching the wrong words.  I just didn't know how to find the right tool.
